# How to turn a cell containing TIME range separated by dash into its minute component?

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a table below with empty column B. How to separate/split column A to give its minute difference as shown in column B below with one line of code?

I tried several attempts like

```
=MINUTE(SPLIT(A1,"-"))
=HOUR(SPLIT(A1,"-")) * 60
=HOUR(TIME(SPLIT(A1,"-")))
=SUM(TIME(SPLIT(A1,"-")))
=EVALUATE(A1)
```

and many others but did not work.

Thank you.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8:00-8:30 | 30 |
| 2 | 8:30-9:00 | 30 |
| 3 | 9:00-9:30 | 30 |
| 4 | 9:30-10:00 | 30 |
| 5 | 10:00-10:30 | 30 |
| 6 | 10:30-11:00 | 30 |
| 7 | 11:00-11:30 | 30 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula:

```
=(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2))-LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1))*1440
```

[image: Result]

If you have Excel 365, you can try the following formula below.

```
=LET(x,FIND("-",B2),y,LEFT(B2,x-1),z,RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-x), (z-y)*1440)
```

Set the  cell format to Number with no decimal place for both formulae.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you perhaps have an alternative for google sheets use? I cant replicate the output in sheets. Thank you very much.

Comment: @dikip See edit. Use the first formula. It should work on any version of Excel and Google Sheets. If your question has been answered successfully, please mark it as answered. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)